# Bitonic sort for key/value array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, opencl

I'm trying to modify [the Intel's Bitonic Sorting](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/bitonic-sorting) algorithm which sorts an array of `cl_int`s, to sort an array of `cl_int2`s (based on the key – i.e. `cl_int2.x`).

The Intel's example consists of a simple host code and one OpenCL kernel which is called multiple times during one sorting operation (multipass).
The kernel loads 4 array items at once as `cl_int4` and operates on them.

I didn't modify the host code algorithm, only the device code. *List of changes in the kernel function:*

- modify the first kernel's parameter type from `int4*` to `int8*` (to load four key-value pairs)
- use only `.even` components of the `theArray`'s elements to compare values (`<`)
- create "`pseudomask`" (`int4`) and based on that, create `mask` as `pseudomask.xxyyzzww` (to capture the values)

**Although the output of my modified kernel is perfectly sorted `cl_int2` array by the first component (`cl_int2.x`), the values (`cl_int2.y`) are incorrect – the value of one item is repeated for the next 4 or 8 items and then new value is used and repeated...**

I'm sure there's a trivial mistake, but I'm unable to find it.

[Diff of the original Intel code and my modified version](https://www.diffchecker.com/1wjns1z1).

### **Edit:** the `cl_int2` array is sorted flawlessly when each key (`cl_int2.x`) is unique.

---

Example input: http://pastebin.com/92qB1csT

Example output: http://pastebin.com/dsU97Npn

(Properly sorted array: http://pastebin.com/Nb56BuQK)

The modified kernel code (commented):

```
// Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Intel Corporation
// https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/bitonic-sorting

// Modified to sort int2 key-value array

__kernel void BitonicSort(__global int8* theArray,
                         const uint stage,
                         const uint passOfStage,
                         const uint dir)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    int8 srcLeft, srcRight, mask;
    int4 pseudomask;
    int4 imask10 = (int4)(0,  0, -1, -1);
    int4 imask11 = (int4)(0, -1,  0, -1);

    if(stage > 0)
    {
        if(passOfStage > 0)    // upper level pass, exchange between two fours,
        {
            size_t r = 1 << (passOfStage - 1);
            size_t lmask = r - 1;
            size_t left = ((i>>(passOfStage-1)) << passOfStage) + (i & lmask);
            size_t right = left + r;

            srcLeft = theArray[left];
            srcRight = theArray[right];
            pseudomask = srcLeft.even < srcRight.even;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

            int8 imin = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
            int8 imax = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

            if( ((i>>(stage-1)) & 1) ^ dir )
            {
                theArray[left]  = imin;
                theArray[right] = imax;
            }
            else
            {
                theArray[right] = imin;
                theArray[left]  = imax;
            }
        }
        else    // last pass, sort inside one four
        {
            srcLeft = theArray[i];
            srcRight = srcLeft.s45670123;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask10;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

            if(((i >> stage) & 1) ^ dir)
            {
                srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);

                srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
                pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
                mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

                theArray[i] = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
            }
            else
            {
                srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

                srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
                pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
                mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

                theArray[i] = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);
            }
        }
    }
    else    // first stage, sort inside one four
    {
        /*
         *  To convert this code to int2 sorter, do this:
         *      1. instead of loading int4, load int8 (key,value, key,value, ...)
         *      2. when there is a vector swizzling, replace component index with two consecutive indices:
         *           srcLeft.yxwz  ->  srcLeft.s23016745
         *         use this rewrite rule:
         *           x  y  z  w
         *           01 23 45 67
         *      3. replace comparison operands with only their keys swizzled:
         *           mask = srcLeft < srcRight;    ->    pseudomask = srcLeft.even < srcRight.even; mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;
         */

        //  make bitonic sequence out of 4.
        int4 imask0 = (int4)(0, -1, -1,  0); // -1 in comparison = true (all bits set - two's complement)
        srcLeft = theArray[i];
        srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;

        /*
         * This XOR mask flips bits, so that in `mask` are the following
         * results (remember that srcRight is srcLeft with swapped component pairs):
         *
         *      [ left.x<left.y, left.x<left.y,    left.w<left.z, left.w<left.z  ]
         *  or: [ left.x<left.y, left.x<left.y,    left.z>left.w, left.z>left.w  ]
         */
        pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask0;
        mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

        if( dir )
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);  // make sure the numbers are sorted like this:
        else
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

        /*
         *  Now the pairs of numbers in `srcLeft` are sorted according to the specified `dir`ection.
         *  If dir == true, then
         *    The components `x` and `y` are swapped so that `x` < `y`. Moreover `z` and `w` are swapped so that `z` > `w`. This resembles up-hill: /\
         *  else
         *    The components `x` and `y` are swapped so that `x` > `y`. Moreover `z` and `w` are swapped so that `z` < `w`. This resembles down-hill: \/
         *
         *  This swapping is achieved by creating `srcLeft`, which is in normal order, and `srcRight`, which has component pairs switched (xyzw -> yxwz).
         *  Then the `mask` is created. The mask bits are redundant because it applies to vector component pairs (so in order to implement key-value sorting,
         *  I have to increase the length of masks!).
         *
         *  The non-ordered component pairs in `srcLeft` are masked out by `mask` while the inverted `mask` is applied to the (pair-wise switched) `srcRight`.
         *
         *  This (the previous) first flipping just makes a 4-bitonic sequence.
         */


        /*
         *  This second step just sorts the bitonic sequence
         */
        srcRight = srcLeft.s45670123; // inverts the bitonic sequence

        // [ left.a<left.c, left.b<left.d,    left.a<left.c, left.b<left.d ]
        pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask10;  // imask10 = (noflip, noflip,  flip, flip)
        mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

        // even or odd (The output of this thread is sorted monotonic sequence. The monotonicity changes and thus preparing bitonic sequence for the next pass.).
        if((i & 1) ^ dir)
        {
            // this sorts the bitonic sequence, hence splitting it
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);

            srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

            theArray[i] = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
        }
        else
        {
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

            srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;

            theArray[i] = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);
        }
    }
}
```

The host-side code:

```
void ExecuteSortKernel(cl_kernel kernel, cl_command_queue queue, cl_mem cl_input_buffer, cl_int arraySize, cl_uint sortAscending)
{
    cl_int numStages = 0;

    cl_int stage;
    cl_int passOfStage;

    for (cl_int temp = arraySize; temp > 2; temp >>= 1)
        numStages++;

    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *) &cl_input_buffer);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 3, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *) &sortAscending);

    for (stage = 0; stage < numStages; stage++) {
        clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *) &stage);

        for (passOfStage = stage; passOfStage >= 0; passOfStage--) {
            clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_uint), (void *) &passOfStage);

            // set work-item dimensions
            size_t gsz = arraySize / (2*4);
            size_t global_work_size[1] = { passOfStage ? gsz : gsz << 1 };    //number of quad items in input array

            // execute kernel
            clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int4 pseudomask; did you mean int8 psuedomask?

Comment: @SamerTufail I think it should be `int4`, because I store `int4` values in it (e.g. `pseudomask = srcLeft.even < srcRight.even` – `srcLeft.even` is `int4`) . Moreover, if I try changing the type to `int8` the code won't compile.

Comment: Apologies, I read it only as srcLeft which is int8

Comment: @SamerTufail nothing to apologise for :) I'm glad someone is reading through my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally resolved the problem!

The tricky part was in the way the original Intel code handled equal values of adjacent pairs inside the loaded 4-tuple — *it didn't explicitly handle it*!

The bugs were present in the very first `stage` **and** in the last `passOfStage` (i.e. `passOfStage = 0`) of every other `stage`s. These parts of code are interchanging individual 2-tuples inside one 4-tuple (represented by the `cl_int8` array `theArray`).

Let's consider this excerpt for example (it doesn't function properly for equal adjacent 2-tuples in the 4-tuple):

```
imask0     = (int4)(0, -1, -1,  0);
srcLeft    = theArray[i];  // int8
srcRight   = srcLeft.s23016745;
pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask0;
mask       = pseudomask.xxyyzzww;
result     = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
```

Imagine what would happen when we'd use this (unfixed) code and `srcLeft.even = (int4)(7,7, 5,5)`. The operation `srcLeft.even < srcRight.even` would result yield `(int4)(0,0,0,0)`, then we'd mask this result by `imask0` and we'd get … `pseudomask = (int4)(0,-1,-1,0)` – i.e. the imask itself. This is, however, wrong.

The `pseudomask`'s value is required to form this pattern: `(int4)(a,a, b,b)` (where `a` and `b` can be either `0` or `-1`). This means that it is sufficient do do the following comparison to form the correct `mask`: `quasimask = srcLeft.s07 < srcRight.s07`. Then the correct mask would be created as `mask = quasimask.xxxxyyyy`. The first 2 `x`es mask the first key-value pair in the first 2-tuple of the 4-tuple (4-tuple = one element in `theArray`). And since we want to bitmask corresponding 2-tuples (which are specified by `imask0` as `0`–`-1` pairs), we add another `xx`. We bitmask analogously for the second 2-tuple in the 4-tuple, which leaves us with `yyyy`.

**Visual example for bitshifting with `imask11`**

```
srcLeft:                        x  y  z  w
                                <  <  <  <
srcRight [relative to srcLeft]: y  x  w  z
^ imask0:                       0 -1  0  1
------------------------------------------
(srcLeft<srcRight)^imask0:      x  x  z  z
```

The fixed, fully functioning version (I've commented the fixed parts):

```
__kernel void BitonicSort(__global int8* theArray,
                         const uint stage,
                         const uint passOfStage,
                         const uint dir)
{
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    int8 srcLeft, srcRight, mask;
    int4 pseudomask;
    int4 imask10 = (int4)(0,  0, -1, -1);
    int4 imask11 = (int4)(0, -1,  0, -1);

    if(stage > 0)
    {
        if(passOfStage > 0)    // upper level pass, exchange between two fours
        {
            size_t r = 1 << (passOfStage - 1);
            size_t lmask = r - 1;
            size_t left = ((i>>(passOfStage-1)) << passOfStage) + (i & lmask);
            size_t right = left + r;

            srcLeft = theArray[left];
            srcRight = theArray[right];
            pseudomask = srcLeft.even < srcRight.even;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyzzww; // here we interchange individual components, so no mask is applied and hence no 2 pairs must contain the same bit-pattern

            int8 imin = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
            int8 imax = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

            if( ((i>>(stage-1)) & 1) ^ dir )
            {
                theArray[left]  = imin;
                theArray[right] = imax;
            }
            else
            {
                theArray[right] = imin;
                theArray[left]  = imax;
            }
        }
        else    // last pass, sort inside one four
        {
            srcLeft = theArray[i];
            srcRight = srcLeft.s45670123;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask10;
            mask = pseudomask.xxyyxxyy;

            if(((i >> stage) & 1) ^ dir)
            {
                srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);

                srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
                pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
                mask = pseudomask.xxxxzzzz; // the 0th and 1st elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 2nd and 3rd)

                theArray[i] = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
            }
            else
            {
                srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

                srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
                pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
                mask = pseudomask.xxxxzzzz; // the 0th and 1st elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 2nd and 3rd)

                theArray[i] = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);
            }
        }
    }
    else    // first stage, sort inside one four
    {
        int4 imask0 = (int4)(0, -1, -1,  0);
        srcLeft = theArray[i];
        srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;

        pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask0;
        mask = pseudomask.xxxxwwww; // the 0th and 1st elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 2nd and 3rd)

        if( dir )
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
        else
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);


        srcRight = srcLeft.s45670123;
        pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask10;
        mask = pseudomask.xxyyxxyy; // the 0th and 2nd elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 1st and 3rd)

        if((i & 1) ^ dir)
        {
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);

            srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
            mask = pseudomask.xxxxzzzz; // the 0th and 1st elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 2nd and 3rd)

            theArray[i] = (srcLeft & mask) | (srcRight & ~mask);
        }
        else
        {
            srcLeft = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);

            srcRight = srcLeft.s23016745;
            pseudomask = (srcLeft.even < srcRight.even) ^ imask11;
            mask = pseudomask.xxxxzzzz; // the 0th and 1st elements must contain the exact same value (as well as 2nd and 3rd)

            theArray[i] = (srcLeft & ~mask) | (srcRight & mask);
        }
    }
}
```